# Is there a way to change the numbers to dots in el-pagination vue?

Tags: vue.js, pagination, styling, element-ui

I am using el-pagination, I want to change the way of displaying from numbers to dotted ones. Is there a way to achieve the same?

From this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

Comment: You could probably override it with some CSS if your package does not support it.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a simple prop to do that unfortunately: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/pagination#attributes At the same time, it's meant to be a pagination and not a carousel so I rather keep it like that for obvious UX reasons.